# Determine : $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[\frac{1 \cdot 1 !+2 \cdot 2 !+\cdots+n \cdot n !}{(n+1) !}\right]^{(n+1)!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit of the following :
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[\frac{1 \cdot 1 !+2 \cdot 2 !+\cdots+n \cdot n !}{(n+1) !}\right]^{(n+1)!}
$$
I think it is clear that the numerator approaches infinity faster than the denominator so the result should be $+\infty$?

Comment: Recall that $1 \cdot 1! + 2 \cdot 2! + ... + n \cdot n! = (n+1)!-1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Note]** : *Notice that $n\cdot n! = (n+1)!-n!$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ go ahead and try to prove that using induction. It follows that* :
\begin{align*}
\lim _{n \to \infty} \left[\displaystyle\frac{1 \cdot 1 !+2 \cdot 2 !+\ldots+n \cdot n !}{(n+1) !}\right]^{(n+1)!}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}\right]^{(n+1)!}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right)^{(n+1)!}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{e}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Same time, same idea ! Cheers :-)

Comment: indeed for math is a wonderful language, cheers!

Answer (score 9):

You have
$$a_n=\Bigg[\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n i\,i!}{(n+1)!}\Bigg]^{(n+1)!}=\Bigg[\frac {(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}\Bigg]^{(n+1)!}=\Bigg[1-\frac {1}{(n+1)!}\Bigg]^{(n+1)!} $$
$$\log(a_n)=(n+1)! \log\Bigg[1-\frac {1}{(n+1)!}\Bigg]\sim -1 $$
$$a_n \sim \frac 1e$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer as well!!